# Creating mail-enabled security group in Azure Active Directory or Exchange Online

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure Active Directory as a base for security/permissions to a Sharepoint 2013 portal. I developing an administration UI using Graph API to load and edit data from the Azure Active Directory. The setup also includes Exchange Online, such that each user defined in the system will be given a mailbox in my domain. The Groups and Users in the Azure Active Directory are synced to the Sharepoint 2013 and Exchange Online using DirSync.

The plan is to use the administration page to consolidate certain expected actions, including creation of new users, connect them to the relevant security groups, as well as creating new mail-enabled security groups.

As is described in the [Graph API Group Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974486.aspx), only "pure" security groups are allowed to be created. Further more, the Graph API does not allow the `mailEnabled` field to be updated to true after creation... In fact, the Azure Active Directory management screen is so limited that a mail-enabled Group cannot be created there either (or am I missing something?).

I am trying to find a solution that will let me still to consolidate all of the actions that I wish to allow under one administration application.

- It seems that PowerShell might be an option, though I am not exactly well-versed in using PowerShell.
- I have tried to find an API that would allow me to connect to Exchange Online and perform similar actions - DirSync seems to sync everything from there to Azure Active Directory just fine - I create a mail-enable security group in Exchange and I get a mail-enabled security group in Azure Active Directory moments later - *I have not been able to find such an API*. **Does it exist?**

Am I looking at it all wrong? Is there a simply solution to my needs as stated above that I am simply not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't sound to me like you're missing something. The thing is, mail-enabled security groups only make sense if you have something providing the "mail". For Microsoft's online services, this would be Exchange. Azure AD and "pure" security groups apply everywhere, but one could argue mail-enabled group only applies if Exchange is in the picture. Anyway, that's an attempt to explain the why.

As to programmatically accessing Exchange, you have many options (see [Exchange Online and Exchange 2013 development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162981(v=office.15).aspx) (in no particular order):

**a) Exchange PowerShell cmdlets**

Exchange allows you to programatically create and manage distribution groups with the [Exchange Online PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200677(v=exchg.150).aspx) cmdlets. For example, the [New-DistributionGroup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998856(v=exchg.150).aspx) cmdlet:

```
New-DistributionGroup -Name "My Favorite People" -Type "Security"
```

As you've noticed, these groups will be synced back to Azure AD as read-only. You can then use them (for example) with Azure AD Graph API to do RBAC based on group membership.

**a.1) Exchange PowerShell cmdlets run from C# code**

If you want to run these cmdlets from other .NET code (e.g. C#), it is doable. Take a look at the example in [How to: Get a list of mail users by using the Exchange Management Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff326159(v=exchg.150).aspx). It can easily be used to get/set groups instead of users.

**b) Exchange Web Service and EWS Managed API**

Your best bet at this point might be to use EWS Management API:

- [Get started with EWS client applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn789003(v=exchg.150).aspx)
- [Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx)

**c) Office 365 API (although this scenario is not currently supported)**

Keep an eye on the Office 365 API, which doesn't look like is support this scenario yet, but looks promising: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much! Going over the links you provided, it seems that PowerShell (run from C# code) is the solution as, apparently, the EWS Managed API doesn't allow the creation of `universal distribution group or security group`.